# Returning a Pointer from a function c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

When I try to compile in C++ it says that there is an undefined reference to sort_Array(int *, int). I have been messing with this for about an hour and I can't figure out why I am getting this error. I thought it was telling me to use a pointer. I have to use the prototype exactly as it is written for the assignment so i can't change the array to a pointer or pass it by reference like I thought it was telling me to. I also have to get the size of the array from the user. Could this be a situation where I need to dynamically allocate the array. It crossed my mind, but I am not sure.

This is the prototype

```
    int *sort_Array(int [], int);
```

This is how I am trying to use it

```
    int size;
    int initial_Array[size];
        cout << "What is the size of your array?" << endl;
        cin >> size;
        cin.ignore();

    sort_Array(initial_Array, size);
```

This is the actual function

```
    int *sort_array(int unsorted_Array[], int size)
    {
        int *sorted_Array, i;
        sorted_Array = new int[size];

    //Function for sorting the array.

        selection_Sort(unsorted_Array, size);

    //Copies the newly sorted unsorted array variable to the sorted array varible.

        for(i=0; i<size; i++)
       {
            unsorted_Array[i] = sorted_Array[i];
       }

     return sorted_Array;
       }
```

Comment: For an easy life, use `std::vector`, and `std::sort`. Modern compilers will not take an unnecessary deep copy if you `return` a `std::vector`.

Comment: He says in the question that "I have to use the prototype exactly as it is written".

Comment: C++ is case-sensitive. `sort_array` is a different function from `sort_Array`.

Comment: Unrelated but, if you are sorting the input array, do you need to return a newed array too? This is a potential memory leak.

Comment: I think I use the same cases for the variable sorted_Array. I do all my variables in that format. I also tried initializing size to 0 as a sort of place holder until it gets initialized later but I am still having the same issues

Comment: I also have to return a dynamically allocated array as per the assignment. I will delete it later.

Comment: Sort the array sent to you, and pass back a pointer to the array that was sent to you.  There is no need to allocate for another array (unless the assignment you were given says so).  Also, `int size; int initial_Array[size];` is not standard.  You cannot declare arrays in C++ using a runtime value for the number of entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `intial_Array` with an uninitialised `size`:

```
int size;
int initial_Array[size];
```

Which is UB.

But your error comes from calling `sort_Array` when you've defined `sort_array`

Comment: This is also a VLA which is not standard.

Comment: "Because you..." What? That leads to a linker error? I know it is UB, but still...

Comment: Still, most of your "answer" is irrelevant to the question being asked.

Comment: Oh wow I am an idiot. I didn't even notice that. I even looked to make sure. I have been looking at that for hours. I just change it and the error went away. Thank you for your help